# raspberry pi image cropping very slow

Tags: python, image, crop, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a project to capture and process photos on a raspberry Pi.
The photos are 6000X4000 about 2 mb, from a nikon D5200 camera.
Everything is working fine, i have made a proof of concept in Java and want to transform this to python or C depending on which language is faster on the raspberry.

No the problem is that the images need to be cropped and re-sized, this takes a very long time in the raspberry. In java the whole process of reading the image, cropping and writing the new image takes about 2 minutes.

I have also tried ImageMagick but in command-line this even takes up to 3 minutes.

With a small python script i made this is reduces to 20 seconds, but this is still a bit to long for my project.

Currently i am installing OpenCV to check if this is faster, this process takes around 4 hours so i thought in the meantime i can ask a question here.

Does anybody have any good idea's or libraries to speed up the process of cropping and re-sizing the images.

Following is the python code i used

```
import Image

def crop_image(input_image, output_image, start_x, start_y, width, height):
    """Pass input name image, output name image, x coordinate to start croping, y     coordinate to start croping, width to crop, height to crop """
input_img = Image.open(input_image)
box = (start_x, start_y, start_x + width, start_y + height)
output_img = input_img.crop(box)
output_img.save(output_image +".jpg")
def main():
   crop_image("test.jpg","output", 1000, 0, 4000, 4000)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: I'd start by trying to pin down what is causing the slowness. IO might be a problem on the Pi, since sd cards are not that fast. However, you say you've got it down to 20s, which might be the best you could hope for. You could try to do it in C, but I'm not sure if that's going to help.

Comment: Yes sorry i did not put that in my question. I see in Java that the most time is spent on ImageIO.read and ImageIO.write. I have not investigated in python yet. What i do see is that my SD card has 30mb/s read so that should not be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

## First approach (without sprites)

```
import pyglet
#from pyglet.gl import *

image = pyglet.resource.image('test.jpg')
texture = image.get_texture()
## -- In case you plan on rendering the image, use the following gl set:
#gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)
texture.width = 1024
texture.height = 768
texture.get_region(256, 192,771, 576)
texture.save('wham.png') # <- To save as JPG again, install PIL
```

## Second attempt (with sprites, unfinished)

```
import pyglet, time
start = time.time() #DEBUG
texture = pyglet.image.load('test.jpg')
print('Loaded image in',time.time()-start,'sec') #DEBUG
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(texture)
print('Converted to sprite in',time.time()-start,'sec') #DEBUG
print(sprite.width) #DEBUG
# Gives: 6000
sprite.scale = 0.5
print('Rescaled image in',time.time()-start,'sec') #DEBUG
print(sprite.width) #DEBUG
# Gives: 3000
```

---

Both solutions end up around 3-5 seconds on an extremely slow PC with a shitty mechanical disk running under Windows XP with.. i can't even count the number of applications running including active virus scans etc.. But note that I can't remember how to save a sprite to disk, you need to access to `AbstractImage` data container within the sprite to get it out.

You will be heavily limited to your disk/memory-card I/O.
My image was 16MB 6000x4000 pixels.. Which i was suprised it whent as fast as 3 seconds to load.

Comment: It seems that getting pyglet on the raspberry pi is a problem. In needs OpenGL drivers where Raspberry has OpenGL ES. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Right, forgot about the fact that OpenGL ES is used (Pygame works on Android so try that. uses GL features but supports ES i think)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `jpegtran`. It provides for lossless cropping of jpeg. It should be in the `libjpeg-progs` package. I suspect that decoding the image to crop it, then re-encoding it is too much for the SD card to take.

Comment: I tried jpegtran, i get about 5 seconds. But i don't see a resize option for jpegtran.

Comment: Sorry I missed the bit about "resizing" Answers to other questions here have mentioned epeg, and there is a blog about it: http://blog.sunekaae.com/2013/04/blazing-fast-epeg-photo-resize-on_3.html On this blog he finds it is 25 times faster than imagemagick on a r-pi. However I haven't tried it myself.